# after adding geom_text_repel, "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only"

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text, geom

I have tried adding a label to one set of points (lnrmssd) on my ggplot chart, but when I used the geom_text_repel function the graph will not appear. If I remove it the graph appears as it should. I have tried a few different variations from tutiorals but each time I have had the same result.

Here is the line of code giving me issues:

```
geom_text_repel(data = hrv, aes(lnrmssd, label = lnrmssd))+
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

When I have tried other variations of the geom_text_repel code I have not recieved any error messages but still the plot does not appear.

Here is a copy of my full code:

````
---
title: "Add Label"
author: "AG"
date: '2022-03-17'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)



library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(here)
library(knitr)
library(caTools)
library(httpuv)
library(zoo)
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
library(smooth)
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggforce)
library(ggrepel)
library(kableExtra)


###data wrangle

hrv <- read_excel(here("hrvdata.xlsx"))
hrv <- na.omit(hrv)

hrv <- hrv %>% mutate("HRVSD" = sd(lnrmssd, na.rm = T),
    "HRVRM" = rollmean(lnrmssd,7, na.pad = T, align = 'right'),
      urmssd = round(HRVRM + 1.5 * HRVSD, 3),
             lrmssd = round(HRVRM - 1.5 * HRVSD, 3),
             l2rmssd = round(HRVRM - .75 * HRVSD, 3))


###Theme
 theme_HRVmarkdown <-  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=80,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"),  
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=60,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black",size=70,angle=0,hjust=.5,vjust=0,face="plain"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black",size=70,angle=90,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 100),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 100, face='bold'),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'azure2', colour=NA),
    legend.key.width = unit(15, 'line'),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(6, 'cm'),
    legend.title = element_text(size=90),
    legend.title.align = 0.5,
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "azure2",
                                colour = "azure2",
                                size = 0.5, linetype = "solid")


)
###CREATE PLOT
  

ggplot()+
   geom_line(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=lnrmssd), colour="grey", size=2.5)+
  geom_line(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=HRVRM), colour="black", size=2.5)+
  geom_line(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=urmssd), colour="green", size=2.5, linetype='dashed')+
  geom_line(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=lrmssd), colour="red", size=2.5, linetype='dashed')+
    geom_line(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=l2rmssd), colour="orange", size=2.5, linetype='dashed')+
 
   geom_point(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=lnrmssd), colour="grey", size=3)+
  geom_point(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=HRVRM), colour="black", size=3)+
  geom_point(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=urmssd), colour="green", size=3)+
  geom_point(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=lrmssd), colour="red", size=3)+
    geom_point(hrv, mapping = aes(x=date, y=l2rmssd), colour="orange", size=3)+
      
### Trying to add label 
geom_text_repel(data = hrv, aes(lnrmssd, label = lnrmssd))+
                   
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.1, alpha=0.9, colour='black')+
    theme_minimal()+
    theme_HRVmarkdown
````

Here is the data I am using:

| date | reading | lnrmssd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 | 68.9077 | 4.232768 |
| 2022-02-18 | 62.4076 | 4.133895 |
| 2022-02-19 | 70.7072 | 4.258547 |
| 2022-02-21 | 81.9841 | 4.406525 |
| 2022-02-22 | 74.8368 | 4.315310 |
| 2022-02-23 | 84.9140 | 4.441639 |
| 2022-02-24 | 72.4620 | 4.283062 |
| 2022-02-25 | 79.0891 | 4.370575 |

How can I alter the code to successfull add a label, rounded to two decimal points, to the points of lnrmssd?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message says that a layer (or more) is expecting an object of class `"POSIXct"`. In the `mutate` try coercing `date = as.POSIXct(date)`.

Comment: as a quick think to check - your `aes(lnrmssd, label = lnrmssd)` call in `geom_text_repel` is telling R to plot the text with the x value equal to `lnrmssd` (i.e., 4.232768, 4.133895 etc.) and the label of the same thing. These x values cannot be plotted on an x scale of dates, which is what your other `geom_` calls are creating.

Comment: Also would suggest using `dput(hrv)` and pasting results in question so we can use your data to test out solutions. The pasted dataframe isn't easy to put into R :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mapped the x variable to `geom_text_repel`. Since all of your layers have the same x mapping, you should include them in the initial `ggplot` call to avoid repetition. Same with the data argument:

```r
ggplot(data = hrv, mapping = aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lnrmssd), colour = "grey", size = 2.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y = HRVRM), colour = "black", size = 2.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y = urmssd), colour = "green", size = 2.5, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_line(aes(y = lrmssd), colour = "red", size = 2.5, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_line(aes(y = l2rmssd), colour = "orange", size = 2.5, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_point(aes(y = lnrmssd), colour = "grey", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = HRVRM), colour = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = urmssd), colour = "green", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = lrmssd), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = l2rmssd), colour = "orange", size = 3) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = date, lnrmssd, label = lnrmssd))
```

[image]

Note though that there is a lot of repetition in your code, and it would be best to pivot your data into long format, particularly if you want a legend:

```r
ggplot(data = tidyr::pivot_longer(hrv, -c(1,2, 4)), 
       mapping = aes(x = date, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = name), size = 2.5) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'orange', 'grey', 'red', 'green')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = date, y = lnrmssd, label = round(lnrmssd, 2)), 
                  data = hrv[c(1, 3)], inherit.aes = FALSE,
                  color = 'black')
```

[image]